# Why preference not working in Magento 2 observer (Custom module)

Tags: magento2, event-observer, special-price, preference

> etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Custom\Pricerule\Observer\Frontend\Catalog\Catalog\ProductGetFinalPrice" type="Lof\RequestForQuote\Observer\ProductGetFinalPrice2" />
```

> observer/ProductGetFinalPrice2.php

```
   <?php
    namespace Lof\RequestForQuote\Observer;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerModelSession;
    use Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory as RuleFactory;
    use Custom\Pricerule\Helper\Data;
    use PaarthMage\Document\Model\DocFactory as DocFactory;
    class ProductGetFinalPrice2 implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
    {

        protected $customerSession;

        protected $catalogRuleFactory;
        protected $helper;
 public function __construct(

        CustomerModelSession $customerSession,
        RuleFactory $catalogRuleFactory,
        DocFactory $DocFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
        Data $helper

        ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->docFactory =  $DocFactory;
        $this->catalogRuleFactory =  $catalogRuleFactory;
        $this->_state = $state;
        $this->helper =  $helper;

        }


    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
$event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();


    $productFinalPrice=100;
     $product->setData('special_price', $productFinalPrice);
       $product1=$product->getSpecialprice();

        }
        return $this;
        }
        }
    }
```

Why I am getting special in this module preference not working in my `Lof_RequestForQuote` module how I can solve this?

Comment: your `ProductGetFinalPrice2` should extend ProductGetFinalPrice

Comment: i'm extending that calss i want the same action performed in productGetPrice

Comment: I mean it should be like this `class ProductGetFinalPrice2 extends \Custom\Pricerule\Observer\Frontend\Catalog\Catalog\ProductGetFinalPrice implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
    {`

Comment: no...............................................

Comment: i have one question???

Answer (score 1):

Add below sequence at **Lof\RequestForQuote\etc\module.xml**

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Custom_Pricerule"/>
</sequence>
```

Add below code to your observer:

```
<?php
namespace Lof\RequestForQuote\Observer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerModelSession;
use Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory as RuleFactory;
use Custom\Pricerule\Helper\Data;
use PaarthMage\Document\Model\DocFactory as DocFactory;

class ProductGetFinalPrice2 implements \Custom\Pricerule\Observer\Frontend\Catalog\Catalog\ProductGetFinalPrice
{

    protected $customerSession;

    protected $catalogRuleFactory;
    protected $helper;
    public function __construct(
        CustomerModelSession $customerSession,
        RuleFactory $catalogRuleFactory,
        DocFactory $DocFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
        Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->docFactory =  $DocFactory;
        $this->catalogRuleFactory =  $catalogRuleFactory;
        $this->_state = $state;
        $this->helper =  $helper;
        parent::__construct($customerSession, $catalogRuleFactory, $DocFactory, $state, $helper);
    }


    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();


        $productFinalPrice=100;
        $product->setData('special_price', $productFinalPrice);
        $product1=$product->getSpecialprice();

    }
}
```